# There are some "Right of Knowledge Acquisition" in the Right to education?

Tags: open-definition

[Educational rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_education) and the [Freedom of information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_information_laws_by_country) (FOI) are in the "Fundamental Rights", and are adopted *as law* in many countries.

The FOI establish a kind of "right-to-know" in the governance sphere, and the [Educational rights](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_to_education) complement it in other spheres: **there are a more specific "Right of Knowledge Acquisition"?**

---

PS: "[knowledge acquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_acquisition)" is a jargon of artificial intelligence technology (an [intelligent agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligent_agent) is the [subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1122451/287948) of this *acquisition*), and also a method of learning in the Aristotelian tradition... We can use here as "*knowledge acquisition* for [person](http://schema.org/Person)", an intersection of  both.